# Select count from sub table

Tags: mysql, performance, select, join, count

I need to get the count from one of the sub tables / joined tables involved in the query. I will demonstrate with a simple example:

**Table: user**

```
    id             name            etc
-------------------------------------------
    1               u1
    2               u2
```

**Table: exercise**

```
    id             userId            etc
-------------------------------------------
    1               1
    2               1
```

Now I need to **select from user table various fields like `id`, `name`, `etc` along with the count of various user id in `exercise` table**.

For example, in the above case I need **the output**:

```
    id             name            count
-------------------------------------------
    1               u1               2 --since two u1's are present in exercise
    2               u2               0 --since no u2's are present in exercise
```

I tried this: but I get syntax error:

```
--actual query is very complex
SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(e.*)
FROM   user AS u
JOIN   exercise AS e ON u.id =  e.userId
```

I tried this: but I get syntax error again:

```
--actual query is very complex
SELECT u.id, u.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM e)
FROM   user AS u
JOIN   exercise AS e ON u.id =  e.userId
```

This works, as a sub query, but is painfully slow (5 to 13 seconds for about 10000 rows in each table):

```
--actual query is very complex
SELECT u.id, u.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exercise WHERE e.userId = u.id)
FROM   user AS u
```

Is there a way I can get the `count` info in one single query, with the help of `join` or so? Sub query is very slow for my needs.

Comment: Have you explored `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @AzizShaikh I have, I think I know it well, but in this one case I can't get it to work. Some brain fart moment for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a `GROUP BY`, like this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(e.userId)
FROM   user AS u
LEFT JOIN exercise AS e 
ON u.id =  e.userId
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Ok I get it, I will have to beef up my sql-fu. One question, why do you use left join here?

Comment: Because left join means retrieve all the records from the main table ie user and related records from secondary table ie exercise. http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Comment: @IHashable Left join will still return you row from user table even if there are no records in exercise table.

Comment: @AzizShaikh I think `u.name` will be needed in group by clause.

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh, I tried this, this is again so slow, almost as slow as the subquery approach. And there is a catch as well. In my main query duplicates are returned. Now doing `count(e.userId)` returns the duplicated count as well. But +1 for the direction.

Comment: @IHashable you are welcome. To improve query performance, you may have to use INDEXes. But first start from [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html). Also @Bhushan is correct, the `GROUP BY` clause should also contain `u.name`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(e.userId)
FROM  user AS u
LEFT JOIN exercise AS e 
ON u.id =  e.userId
GROUP BY u.id,u.name
```

Left join will still return you row from `user` table even if there are no records in `exercise` table.